# Joining a view for every row in second view with no common field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view with a single column that has months and another view with several columns. Both views have no common fields.

VIEW A:

```
C1       C2            C3
21       SSSSS         AAAAA
11       SSSSS         AAAAA
55       SSSSS         AAAAA
```

VIEW B:

```
MONTH
1-1-2018
1-2-2018
```

I need to find a way that, for every month, the whole VIEW A is joined next to the month.

VIEW A + B:

```
C1       C2            C3       MONTH
21       SSSSS         AAAAA    1-1-2018
11       SSSSS         AAAAA    1-1-2018
55       SSSSS         AAAAA    1-1-2018 
21       SSSSS         AAAAA    1-2-2018
11       SSSSS         AAAAA    1-2-2018
55       SSSSS         AAAAA    1-2-2018
```

I'm using Oracle but this is fairly standard I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a Cartesian product -- `cross join`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from viewa a cross join viewb b;
```

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla Gordon is right, you are describing a cartesian join. One word of caution though. If you have 10 rows in each table, it's not A+B = 20 rows. It's A*B=100 rows. You can very quickly end up with a massive dataset that will test the limits of you server's memory.